# Regular expression matching more than one occurrences of given groupe

Tags: python, regex

I'm struggling with regular expression. I test it out using [this](http://pythex.org)
so its not my code (not yet :P). So, i have a long and nasty string, looks more or less like that:

`&#xA;&lt;im a really nasty string from hell/&gt;&#xA;&lt;still a nasty string from hell/&gt;&#xA;&lt;oh, this is part i need/&gt;&lt;&#xA;&lt;im a really nasty string from hell/&gt`;

what i want:

```
&#xA;&lt;oh, this is part i need/&gt;
```

i try to catch it with that:

```
(&#xA\;&lt;)(.|\n|\t)*?(need)(.|\n|\t)*?(\/&gt;)
```

but it catches to much.. like that:

```
&#xA;&lt;im a really nasty string from hell/&gt;&#xA;&lt;still a nasty string from hell/&gt;&#xA;&lt;oh, this is part i need/&gt;
```

so end part works as intended, but it grabs to much at the beginning, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Put this (.|\n|\t)*?(need)(.|\n|\t)*? in another Subpattern ((.|\n|\t)*?(need)(.|\n|\t)*?).

Comment: Nop, this still catches to much. I also tried ((&#xA\;&lt;)(.|\n|\t)*?).(need)(.|\n|\t)*?(\/&gt;) but its still grabs to much.

Comment: Do you know what characters should be matched or should not be matched? If yes, then it is easy.

Comment: Not characters, groups of those yes, but not single char :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could require that your captured string does not include a slash:

[`&#xA;&lt;([^\/]*?need[\S\s]*?)\/&gt;`](https://regex101.com/r/sdN5Ac/7)

Or, alternatively, you could allow slashes, but not `&gt;`. In that case do:

[`&#xA;&lt;((?:(?!\/&gt;)[\S\s])*?need[\S\s]*?)\/&gt;`](https://regex101.com/r/sdN5Ac/8)

Comment: thank you, that second solution did the trick, and i can use it in all use-cases that i have.